# Create Pagination jquery with for loop

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, pagination

Ok, here's my problem. I am working with specific load functions and i need to make for loop for pagination so it dinamically load content instead of repeating blocks of code.

```
 $('.teoBtn_1').click(function() {
    hideAll();
    $('#contentorTopico').load(unidadeSessao + "_t1" + '.html', function(){
        $('#contentorTopico').show();
        $('.nome_topico').text(topicoName);
        });
});

    $('.teoBtn_2').click(function() {
    hideAll();
    $('#contentorTopico').load(unidadeSessao + "_t2" + '.html', function(){
        $('#contentorTopico').show();
        $('.nome_topico').text(topicoName);
        });
});

    $('.teoBtn_3').click(function() {
    hideAll();
    $('#contentorTopico').load(unidadeSessao + "_t3" + '.html', function(){
        $('#contentorTopico').show();
        $('.nome_topico').text(topicoName);
        });
});

    $('.teoBtn_4').click(function() {
    hideAll();
    $('#contentorTopico').load(unidadeSessao + "_t4" + '.html', function(){
        $('#contentorTopico').show();
        $('.nome_topico').text(topicoName);
        });
});

    $('.praBtn_1').click(function() {
    hideAll();
    $('#contentorTopico').load(unidadeSessao + "_t5" + '.html', function(){
        $('#contentorTopico').show();
        $('.nome_topico').text(topicoName);
        });
});

        $('.praBtn_2').click(function() {
    hideAll();
    $('#contentorTopico').load(unidadeSessao + "_t6" + '.html', function(){
        $('#contentorTopico').show();
        $('.nome_topico').text(topicoName);
        });
});


        $('.praBtn_3').click(function() {
    hideAll();
    $('#contentorTopico').load(unidadeSessao + "_t7" + '.html', function(){
        $('#contentorTopico').show();
        $('.nome_topico').text(topicoName);
        });
});
```

I repeat all the actions on click of teoButton_1 2 and 3 etc... to load _t1, _t2 and _t3,how can i transform it to the for loop with no need to specify 1 2 or 3 numbers every time?
Can anyone help?

Html of my pagination:

```
 <div class="pagination">
     <a class="at teoBtn_1" href="#">1</a>
     <a class="at teoBtn_2" href="#">2</a>
     <a class="at teoBtn_3" href="#">3</a>
     <a class="at teoBtn_4" href="#">4</a>
     <a class="ap teoBtn_5" href="#">5</a>
     <a class="ap teoBtn_6" href="#">6</a>
     <a class="ap teoBtn_7" href="#">7</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you provide the html of that?

Comment: I can provide the pagination html, but not all the loaded .html docs

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is really easy, just use for in pure javascript:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) { // will loop 7 times
$('.teoBtn_' + i).click(function() {
    hideAll();
    $('#contentorTopico').load(unidadeSessao + "_t" + i + '.html', function(){
        $('#contentorTopico').show();
        $('.nome_topico').text(topicoName);
        });
});
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, Thanks =)

Comment: you can improve it changing
`for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)` to `(i = 0; i < $('.pagination a').length; i++)` to detect the amount of links inside pagination.